# perl problem to get desired output

Tags: regular-expression, perl

```
nameFile
seq_1014
seq_1039
seq_2848
seq_3213
seq_6847
seq_6980
seq_6997
seq_9319
seq_9561
seq_9850
# outputFile
>seq_1014
>seq_1039
>seq_2848
>seq_3213
>seq_6847
>seq_6980
>seq_6997
>seq_9319
>seq_9561
>seq_9850
>seq_10140
>seq_10141
>seq_10142
>seq_10143
>seq_10144
>seq_10145
>seq_10146
###Scriptuse

#!/usr/bin/env perl
my $list_file = $ARGV[0];
my $fasta_in = $ARGV[1];
my $fasta_out = $ARGV[2];
open(LIST_FILE, "<", $list_file) or die "could not open '$list_file' : $! \n";
open(FASTA_IN, "<", $fasta_in) or die "could not open '$fasta_in' : $! \n";
open(FASTA_OUT, ">", $fasta_out) or die "could not open $fasta_out : $! \n";
my @headers = ();
while(<LIST_FILE>) {
    chomp;
    next if ( /^\s*$/ );
    push(@headers, $_);
}
my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @headers;
$/ = ">";
while(<FASTA_IN>) {
    chomp;
    if ( /$pat/ ) { print FASTA_OUT ">$_"; }
}
close(LIST_FILE);
close(FASTA_IN);
close(FASTA_OUT);
```

Problem is unwanted output

```
>seq_10140
>seq_10141
>seq_10142
>seq_10143
>seq_10144
>seq_10145
>seq_10146
```

I just want the exact names to match and grep fasta sequences but this script is messing like i just want seq_1014 and it also gives

```
>seq_10140
>seq_10141
>seq_10142
>seq_10143
>seq_10144
>seq_10145
>seq_10146
```

How can I fix this script to get desired output

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help for editing help...

Answer (score 0):

So two problems:

1. Unwanted matches: This is because you didn't end each clause of the pattern to have *$* at the end to indicate that you want to match *abced* followed by **nothing**.  *seq_10140* **does** match *seq_1014* because *seq_1014* **is** in there (somewhere).  You didn't say that another character at the end would cause a fail by saying *seq_1014$*.
2. Failing to match when it should:  This part works on my system when I copy out your code and your input files.  *1039* and so on **do** match. All I can think of is that your *$pat* is just one clause long due to some problem with your pattern file that's being fixed by cut-and-pasting it into and out of this forum.  Usually this means that there are two *End Of Line* characters at the end of each line a la DOS and the whole file gets read in on the first read.  There are, however, a host of other things that could be wrong with them.  Take it into debug or just add print statements to see what's in *@headers* and *$pat*.  Get a byte-by-byte output of the file via a 'C' program or Emacs in 'hexl-mode' to see if anything in there is confusing your reads.